# Source filtering for first of nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) on a query to just return a small set of information and within that information I want the first photo url of an object:

```
"query" : { ... },
"_source" : ["name", "photos.thumbnail_url"]
```

Of course this returns the `thumbnail_url` for all of the photos stored against each item.

Is there any way to get just the first nested photo's `thumbnail_url` using source filtering?

(I appreciate that one way to do it would be to index the first photo separately and just source filter to include that separate field but I'm asking whether it is possible without a separate field.)

(I've guessed a few approaches without luck: `photos.0.thumbnail_url`, `photos[0].thumbnail_url`, `photos.first.thumbnail_url`)

Comment: Have you tried [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options) with `size: 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Just an attempt, as I don't know your mapping, with [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options):

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "_source": ["name"], 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "whatever"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "photos",
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "inner_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["thumbnail_url"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or use a [script field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-script-fields.html):

```
  "script_fields": {
    "FIELD": {
      "script": "urls=_source.photos.thumbnail_url;return urls[0]"
    }
  }
```

and I don't think it's possible to do this with source filtering.

Comment: Yep, that definitely returns just one photo thumbnail url. I can't seem to get it to return the first one though but I can index an, er, index field easily enough to sort on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The question is what does "first" mean to you? First as you indexed (like `source` first) or "first" by other definitions?

Comment: First as I indexed, yes, perhaps that just needs to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: You tested with script_field or inner_hits?

Comment: I need to be a bit more explicit all round :) I tested with inner hits - my expectation is that script_field will return the first in the source but I've not got to testing that yet (have scripting off at the moment).

Comment: Oh, then it might explain why the order is not kept for `inner_hits`.

Comment: is the syntax version dependent? 5.6 docs ask me to use  params['_source']